# Convert time to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

Inside `db table` I have column

`MyTime` where data type is `time(7)`

Representation in domain entity is

```
public DateTime MyTime { get; set; }
```

my question is:
how can I convert MyTime property to return data as DateTime cause this way I'm getting following error

> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not
>   valid.

p.s. I don't want to change DateTime data type in domain entity.

Comment: What have you tried already?  You posted what your issue is, but what have you already tried to resolve this?

Comment: Why not change it to `TimeSpan`?  `time(7)` cannot represent a date so it would be a more natural fit.

Comment: Hint: DateTime is an integer value representing X time since the epoch (January 1, 1970). As such, it doesn't have a "Date" or a "Time" per se. So, if you want to use a DateTime, you need to use seconds/milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: Agree with @juharr here. If you absolutely need a DateTime, you'll need to assign an arbitrary day (if you wanted to use epoch, it would be new DateTime(1970,1,1,myHours,myMinutes,mySeconds)). Otherwise, use a timespan

Answer (score 0):

Use TimeSpan instead of DateTime

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change your database query to return the `time(7)` value as datetime.

I.e. instead of:

```
SELECT ... MyTime ...
```

you can use

```
SELECT ... CAST(MyTime AS DATETIME) AS MyTime ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible directly as time is duration and its not date. But if you have reference date then you can do it.

```
static DateTime GetDateTime(string timeStr)
  { 
     return DateTime.Parse("01/01/2012 " + timeStr);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data access layer where you are reading the value for the column of type time(7) you should be able to cast it to a DateTime object as follows:

```
myObj.MyTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToString(reader["my_time_column_in_db"]));
```

In the above, "my_time_column_in_db" is the name of the column defined as type time(7) in your database. The resulting myObjTime.MyTime property will end up with today's date for the mm/dd/yyyy portion and will have whatever value was returned from the database for its hh:mm:ss part.